# What did an Ethernet "transparent bridge" used to look like?

Tags: networking, ethernet, bridge

I hope this is the right forum to ask this question. It's not really a technical problem, but it is technical question I think a power user/enthusiast would ask.

My Cisco book describes devices known as "Ethernet transparent bridges" that predate the modern switch. I tried to google around to find a picture of one, but could not. For my curiosity, does anyone have a picture of one of these ancient things or ever worked with one of them?

I know they're probably not that fascinating to look at, but I always read about this old hardware (like networking equipment that actually supported the OSI protocol) that was supposedly in the wild at one time, but can never find any pics or info on the actual devices.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out these devices:

[image: 3com bridges]
From 3Com

[image: IP Tech]
From IP Technology Labs

Comment: So cool thanks! Reminds me of these devices we use to call "media converters" that had AUI and BNC ports on one end and an Rj45 on the other.